# SQL 2008 Central Management Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to register a server to your CMS and use SQL Authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use SQL authentication with the CMS.  It's Windows authentication only.  It doesn't store any authentication data inside the CMS - it's only a list of registered servers.

Comment: and no possible workaround?

Comment: Yeah, sadly no.  Same problem with multiple domains without a trust between 'em too.

Comment: found this connect item, can we get people to vote?

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=381185

Answer (score 0):

When you register your CMS there's a drop down with Authentication. Change that to SQL Server Authentication (if I'm understanding you correctly)

Comment: thanks, but that is just for the connection to the CMS. I am looking to register instances to the CMS, and the option for authentication is disabled. i tried an import/export, but the option was changed (and disabled) upon import.

Comment: and how the hell do you have 186 points and three badges already? where have i been?